# Number of ways to make grid

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, algorithms

I need to construct a L x 3 grid as shown below [image]

But i can use only two shapes to make it which are :
[image]

Here L is the number of small square boxes in each row. I can rotate the shapes as I want. **I need to find the number of unique ways in which we can construct the grid using these shapes only.**

EXAMPLE : 
If L=4 then there are 3 ways to make it that are : [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is not a multiple of $4$ it is easy-you can't do it.  Let us define $S(n)$ as the number of ways to make a rectangle $3 \times 4n,\ T(n)$ as the number of ways to make a rectangle $3 \times 4n$ plus a stairstep (in either orientation).  The critical thing to notice is that stairsteps need to match.  Now write the recurrences $$S(0)=1,T(0)=2,S(1)=3 \\S(n)=S(n-1) + T(n-1) \\ T(n)=2S(n)+T(n-1)\\T(n)-T(n-1)=2S(n)$$ where the second says you can get a $3 \times 4n$ rectangle either by starting with a $3 \times 4(n-1)$ rectangle and adding three $1 \times 4$'s or by taking a $[3 \times (n-1)$ rectangle plus stairstep] and adding a stairstep.  The third line says we can get a rectangle plus stairstep either by adding three $1 \times 4$'s to a shorter rectangle plus stairstep, or by starting with a rectangle and adding a stairstep.  If we subtract the second shifted down one from the second we get $$S(n)-S(n-1)=S(n-1)+T(n-1)-S(n-2)-T(n-2)\\ =S(n-1)-S(n-2)+2S(n-1)\\S(n)=4S(n-1)-S(n-2)$$ which can be solved by standard techniques.

Comment: its wrong.Answer for n=2(or according to me for L=8) should be 11.

Comment: Its wrong.Answer for n=2(or according to me for L=8) should be 11.

Comment: I only find $7$.  Let $S$ be a stairstep with the long on top, $T$ a stairstep with the long on the bottom, and $U$ a set of three $1 \times 4$s.  I find $UU, STU, SUT, UST, TSU, TUS, TSU$  What are your other four?

Comment: I dont know how to tell you but their are 11 ways as i cant dreaw 11 pictures here

Comment: let me try what about withiut takng Us and 2 sets of S and Ts.That is STST like this type

Comment: You are right.  I'll update.  The framework will work.

Comment: here are the 11 ways : http://postimg.org/image/5zfq6jf87/e7304302/ and http://postimg.org/image/hd3d15n65/d8ddf49f/

Comment: I was off by one in the $T(n)$ recurrence.  Fixed.  Thanks.